# AngularJS Routing fails to inject module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been trying few examples and I tried routing and injecting a template into HTML. It fails to inject the module inside an HTML div.

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <script src="Script/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/angualr-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Script.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <table style="font-family:Arial">
        <tr>
            <td  class="leftMenu">

                <a href="#/aboutme">About Me</a><br /><br />
                <a href="#/contact">Contact</a><br /><br />
            </td>
            <td class="mainContent">
                 <div ng-view></div>
            </td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Script.js:

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/aboutme", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/aboutme.html",
        controller: "aboutmeController"
    })
    .when("/contact", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/contact.html",
        controller: "contactController"
    })
})
```

I am not sure what is missing. Can someone point out the issue or provide suggestion?

I found this error in the Console tab of Developer tools:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeprovider
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:121
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:362)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:38:64)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:38:188
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:7:333)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:37:488)
    at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:249)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:19:463
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Claies Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Comment: you have a typo in your script tag.  `<script src="Script/angualr-route.min.js"></script>`.  it's **angular**, not **angualr**

Comment: no claies that is not the issue.

Comment: @Claies https://plnkr.co/edit/Gq6HYbL1M3SsdXS9uTau?p=info

Comment: the code in that plunker doesn't even match the code here;  in this question here, you have a typo, in the plunker, you have a **different** typo**s** (`$routeProvider` vs `$routeprovider`, also `index.html` vs `Index.html`.  Case is important!).  You should really try using the non-minified versions of scripts when tying to find spelling/capitalization mistakes like this.

Comment: also, you will crash the browser if you try to load your `index.html` ***page*** as a ***template*** in a route....

Answer (score 3):

You should also write a controller for your app in the Script.js. So, in your case, try this:

```
    app.controller('MyApp', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

Comment: also, I hope you have the aboutme.html and contact.html files in the 'Templates' directory

Comment: I am gettting Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Answer (score 0):

Add the necessary controllers code in your js file. Otherwise it will say controller is not defined.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/aboutme", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/aboutme.html",
        controller: "aboutmeController"
    })
    .when("/contact", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/contact.html",
        controller: "contactController"
    })
})

app.controller("aboutmeController", function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = "test";
});

app.controller("contactController", function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = "test";
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/kAViZosR3xDyk53TIEWx?p=preview)**

Comment: how does this answer the question?  it looks like your code is mostly identical, except for the scripts.

Comment: @Claies no it has the controllers

Comment: @Sajeetharan Please don't just post code. Please also provide an explanation of why this would work. I.e explain to the OP that they need to add some controllers.

Comment: @Kildareflare added

Comment: snippet throws error while running it. i tried adding controllers as you did.It makes no change

Comment: @kaarthickraman issue is you dont have the templates. check the plunker code

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing an error at the developer tools in your landing page itself, then it might be because of missing resources, such as the controllers not being defined, respective html pages not available at the "Templates" directory specified in your code or the typo I notice in your script source for angular-route (**angualr-route.min.js**); assuming file is present/saved with the right name.

You can remove the controllers (if not defined in your Script.js) and just have some content in the templates for the time being, to track down the issue.

If the issue is about navigation not working, it might be because you aren't running it on a local server.

Routing and navigation requires you to run the application in a local server. You can use Tomcat for the same.

Hope this helps.